# Read mail message sent from MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

In an iOS app written with Xamarin, I would like to send a mail and retrieve the sent mail - with any modifications and attachements done to it by the user.

I have implemented the funtion with the MFMailComposeViewController and in the Finished-handler I get the MFComposeResultEventArgs, but I can't see if/where I can get a hold of the actual mail message.

In the back of my mind I think I've heard that one must override the MFMailComposeViewController to accomplish this, but I can't google/bing this.

Is there anyone out there who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Put simple: You don't. Apple in keeping this information from you by purpose, they are taking the user's privacy quite serious.

If you need to keep track of this kind of information, do not use email but instead maybe a form to send data to your server.

Comment: If this is the official stance from Apple I disagree. I can of course create my own send mail view within my app and add all the features of the native view, such as add attachement, and then store the mail within my app before I send it. 
I'm not interested in reading the other mails sent from my users. The goal is to take advantage of the full features of that particular view to save time. 
But I would also like to store this mail in a central mail log. Are you positive this can't be done?

Comment: There might be some obscure hack that uses private API or discouraged subclassing to do so, but I doubt that would hold agaist Apples guidelines. So, no, not 100% sure, but quite confident.